# Chomsky hierarchy for finite state transducers

Tags: finite-automata, chomsky-hierarchy, transducers

In [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/82334/are-finite-state-transducers-and-mealy-machines-the-same-machines) in the first answer someone mentions a "special transduction hierarchy". I cannot find anywhere anything about it. Could someone point me to resources on this topic?